# How to use different colour to plot in folium map?

Tags: python, folium

So i have many csv files each one of them has three columns.

1. latitude
2. longitude
3. distance

for example:
car1.csv

```
lat     long      total_dist
23.33   73.32.       0
23.45.  73.34.       10
23.64.  73.53.       16 ---> #cumulative sum as car1 travels
#similarly there it for car2,car3,car4 etc
```

so i concatenated these csv file into one data frame to plot map

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from pathlib import Path
import glob

path = r'C:/Users/Desktop/Sample/car_new' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

car_locations = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)


car_locations = car_locations[["Latitude", "Longitude",]]



map = folium.Map(location=[car_locations.Latitude.mean(), car_locations.Longitude.mean()], zoom_start=14, control_scale=True, tiles='Stamen Terrain')

folium.PolyLine(car_locations, color="red", weight=2.5, opacity=0.5).add_to(map)


map
```

i want set conditions like this

```
if(total_dist > 120):
#plot green line on map
else:
#plot red line
```

This is how it should look i have posted a link to the image.
https://imgur.com/a/07rxQ9l

Comment: I experimented by creating test data; since only a single color can be set in Polyline, I added a line with the data extracted by the condition. You can set different colors by adding lines with other data. `folium.PolyLine(car_locations[car_locations['total_dist'] > 120][['lat','lon']].values.tolist(), color="green", weight=5, opacity=0.8).add_to(m)`

Comment: i have tried above code snippet but only above 120 its visible but whole path is not

Answer (score 0):

```
# This script will plot multiple lines
# One line per file, each line in a colour specified in the list.

from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import folium
from pathlib import Path
import glob

#Imported OS module to set path dynamically.
# as seen below.
import os

# Dynamically set project script, this will allow you to
# run the script in any directory without manually
# typing the path
project_dir = os.path.realpath('') + '/'

# This is not necessary, but since this was in your script
# I left it in here.
path = project_dir
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

# List of colors, and a counter.
# this is an easy less complicated way to do it, but not the only way.
colors = ['red', 'blue']
cl_count = 0

# You need to only create the map once
# If this is in the loop, it will create a new map and overwrite
# the map when you plot the second car.
map = folium.Map(zoom_start=14, control_scale=True, tiles='Stamen Terrain')

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
    car_locations = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    car_locations = car_locations[["Latitude", "Longitude",]]
    folium.PolyLine(car_locations, color=colors[cl_count], weight=3.0, opacity=1).add_to(map)
    # You need to clear the list at the end of the loop
    # Since you want the coordinates from each file to plot a unique line.
    li = []
    cl_count += 1
    
map
```